# Scheme for ultimate power plan

Tags: power

I am writing a script, and I need to have power plan activated by scheme. I have the High performance, but I need it for Ultimate plan. Is there a scheme for ultimate power plan? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Power plans have largely disappeared from plain site, largely because they are all some other way of setting the same things. There has not been any "ultimate" power plan for some time now.

So the easiest way forward for you is to change your high performance settings to what you need / want.

Power plans do not create more power - they just adjust settings.  So just change your Plan settings.

You can look here in the Registry for your scheme. The actual registry location may vary a bit depending on machine.

**HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes**\381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e\238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20\29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da\DCSettingIndex: 0x00000258

Comment: Ok, thanks. But, is there a scheme, like here; scheme_max, power saver
scheme_min, high performance
scheme_balanced, balanced

Comment: The "Ultimate" Plan existed in Windows 7 but started disappearing after that.  Your comment says "like here"   --  Like where?   If you have a script for High Performance  (Windows 10, not 11) adjust the script parameters.

Comment: I added a sample registry location for your schemes.